# UISwitch in custom UITableViewCell Reuse Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

The issue is as follows: I have a tableview with a custom cell. That cell contains a label and a UISwitch. I have set the label.text value to an array, but the UISwitch is getting reused.

Example: If I toggle the switch in the first row, the 5th row gets enabled, and if I scroll it continues to reuse the cells and cause issue.

Video : https://vimeo.com/247906440

View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let array = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.label.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }
}
```

Custom Cell:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var toggleSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

I realize there isn't code trying to store this data because I haven't been successful. Any ideas would be helpful. The project currently uses the MVC model and I believe that is the answer but just need some help.

Comment: Where are you saving the on/off state of the `toggleSwitch` ? Since it can be reused anytime you scroll the `UITableView`, I suggest you to don't rely on any `IBOutlet`. You should implement a model for storing the informations, and then use that model for `injecting` the UI you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to you create cellViewModel class and keep array of it instead of just string. You cellViewModel may look like,

```
class CellViewModel {
 let title: String
 var isOn: Bool

init(withText text: String, isOn: Bool = false /* you can keep is at by default false*/) {
    self.title = text
    self.isOn = isOn
}
```

Now, build array of CellViewModel

```
let array =["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"]
var cellViewModels = [CellViewModel]()
for text in array {
    let cellViewModel = CellViewModel(withText: text)
    cellViewModels.append(cellViewModel)
}
```

Change your tableVieDelegate function to :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    let cellViewModel = cellViewModels[indexPath.row]
    cell.label.text = cellViewModel.title
    cell.toggleSwitch.isOn = cellViewModel.isOn
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

In you Custom Cell class, add this protocol :

```
protocol CellActionDelegate: class {
    func didChangeSwitchStateOnCell(_ cell: CustomTableViewCell)
}
```

Add delegate as property in your custom cell,

```
weak var delegate: CellActionDelegate?
```

Also, on switch change, add this line,

```
delegate?.didChangeSwitchStateOnCell(self)
```

Now, your viewController should register and listen to this delegate :
I have added line cellForRowAtIndexPath to register for delegates. To listen this delegate, add this function in your VC.

```
func didChangeSwitchStateOnCell(_ cell: CustomTableViewCell) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    cellViewModels[indexPath.row].isOn = cell.toggleSwitch.isOn
}
```

Comment: Would that be as simple as a IBOutlet from the switch assigning the isOn boolean to true? Anyway you could add that part to your answer? Thanks so much!

Comment: Your cell would be listening to  Switch action. You would need to delegate this change to VC. Sure. Let me add it for you.

Answer (score 1):

start creating a model for example :

```
struct item {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var isActivated: Bool

    init(id: String, name: String, isActivated: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.isActivated = isActivated
    }

}

let item1 = item(id: "1", name: "One", isActivated: false)
let item2 = ...........
let item3 = ...........
let items [item1, item2, item3]
```

With that you can trigger the boolean if it's activated or not.

You will also have to take a look to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse I think.

Comment: This is a great answer but I am going to use Makund's because it sticks to the MVC model of the rest of my project. Thanks so much for your help :)